# How to store character code in a JavaScript Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, character, special-characters, uint8array

In the function **toCharArr** the argument ***arr*** is an "array of characters" 
{ Example: `arr = ['H','e','l','l','o']` }

```
function toCharArr(arr) {
    const res = new Uint8Array(arr.length); 
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
       res[i] = arr[i];
    return res;
}
```

In the code above **res** array should ideally contain the characters **['H','e','l','l','o']** or the codes for these characters, but instead it contains only 5 **zeros**. This problem is baffling me as it seems to simple but yet so complex.

What have I done wrong here? Should I get the character code?

Any help would be great.

Comment: As I think Uint8Array used for occupying less memory and used with integer value.
so, if you assign any integer value it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to reference which index of the array you want to get the charcode of - 
`arr[i]` and then get the charCodeAt index 0 `arr[i].charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: thats it. Fixed.

Comment: please delete the first line of your answer as I had made a small typo in my question. Your second sentence is the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same like this:

```js
function toCharArr(str) {
    return str.split('').map(elem => elem.charCodeAt(0));
}

const result = toCharArr('hello');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: please delete the first line of your answer as I had made a small typo in my question.

Comment: So, that in future the readers of this question should not be confused.